# rpm install use current timestamp

Tags: time, rpm, stamp

rpm install ko module.

need run `depmod -A` to update `module.dep`, but the timestamp of ko files isn't current timestamp.

so can use current time stamp of installed file during rpm installing

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing build time with install time: they are different time stamps.

Comment: i want to have using install time instead of building time on rpm install